# SQL Server does not commit update

Tags: sql-server-2012

I'm trying to update a table column with trailing whitespaces. I'm using the following query:

```
UPDATE TABLE_WITH_SPACES
SET TABLE_ID = REPLACE(TABLE_ID, ' ', '')
WHERE TABLE_ID LIKE '% '
```

I have tried variations of the above, and every time the result is the same:

> "2000 row(s) affected"

but running:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM TABLE_WITH_SPACES
WHERE TABLE_ID LIKE '% '
```

Reveals the update did nothing. I checked the table for triggers, tried surrounding the update statement with BEGIN TRANSACTION/COMMIT TRANSACTION, but nothing is working.

Am I doing something wrong?

Please, I'm losing my mind over this simple query.

Comment: `update [table] set [table_id] = rtrim([table_id]) where table_id like '% '`?

Comment: Also, is the column type `char` or `varchar`?

Comment: Column is of type char. Using RTRIM/TRIM I have the same issue

Comment: If it's a `char` it's fixed width, no amount of trimming will make it smaller, @sleepster . If you don't want trailing spaces, you want a `varchar`.

Comment: For example, take a `char(5)` with the value `'abc  '`. If you use *any* of the `TRIM` functions on that value you end up with `'abc  '`.

Comment: I see, thanks for the explanation. If you submit an answer I will accept it